# How to condtion row when there are no more rows in vb net and sql Server

Tags: vb.net, ssms

i want to display a message box when theres is no more row in datagrid view when im deleting saying
no record to delete, heres what im using

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\UserDb;Initial Catalog=vbLoginForm;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE [dbo].[Customers] SET [Customer's Name] ='" + txtName.Text + "' ,[Address] = '" + txtAddress.Text + "',[Mobile #] = '" + txtNumber.Text + "',[Order] = '" + txtOrder.Text + "',[Rental] = '" + txtRental.Text + "'WHERE [Customer's Name] = '" + txtName.Text + "'", con)
    Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    sda.Fill(dt)

    If (dt.Rows.Count < 0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("No record to delete.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Else
        If MessageBox.Show("Delete Record?", "Prompt", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            txtAddress.Text = ""
            txtName.Text = ""
            txtOrder.Text = ""
            txtRental.Text = ""
            txtNumber.Text = ""
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted Successfuly", "Delete Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            CustomersBindingSource.MoveNext()

            con.Close()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Aborted!", "Prompt", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Row count cannot be less than 0. It would be equal to zero if there are no rows.

Comment: `dt.Rows.Count` will never be `<` (less) than 0, you should change your condition to `=` (equal) instead

Comment: yeah i did use the = but the row 0 is not deleting, is there another way i can use?

Comment: You'd need to show your full delete process in order to get further assistance.

Comment: Yikes, this looks scary vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: Also, an `UPDATE` statement will never return any rows back. This will **always** have an empty DataTable.

Comment: what should i do then any tips?

Comment: my prof giving us a hard time he just taught us how to connect db to vbnet and then he said we create a system aha. without teaching anything hahaha. i was hoping here someone can help me

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn im using InventoryBindingSource.RmoveCurrent() so it will disappear, but when nothing is there when i push delete button it will yellowhighlight the removecurrent. thats why i need a condition to make the message pop if nothing/no rows

Comment: I'm a little lost on exactly what you're trying to achieve here.  You keep mentioning deleting records, yet the sql command you executing is an Update, not a Delete.  Is that really what you're trying to do in the Database?

Comment: oh so this code is for updating not for deleting? what should i use then?

Comment: the mention of a professor suggests you're supposed to figure that out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are confuse what exactly you want to do . Here I posting code based on my assumption

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\UserDb;Initial Catalog=vbLoginForm;Integrated Security=True")
Con.open()
try

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from  [dbo].[Customers] where [Customer's Name] =@CustomerName and [Address] = @address and [Mobile #] = @MobileNo and [Order] = @order and [Rental] = @rental" , con)
    Cmd.parameters.add(@CustomerName,sqlDbtype.Nvarchar).value = txtName.text
    Cmd.parameters.add(@address ,sqlDbtype.Nvarchar).value = txtaddress.text
    Cmd.parameters.add(@MobileNo ,sqlDbtype.Nvarchar).value = txtnumber.text
    Cmd.parameters.add(@order ,sqlDbtype.Nvarchar).value = txtorder.text
    Cmd.parameters.add(@rental ,sqlDbtype.Nvarchar).value = txtrental.text
    Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    sda.Fill(dt)

    If (dt.Rows.Count = 0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("No record to delete.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Else
        If MessageBox.Show("Delete Record?", "Prompt", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            
           cmd = new sqlcommand("Delete from [dbo].[Customers] where [Customer's Name] =@CustomerName and [Address] = @address and [Mobile #] = @MobileNo and [Order] = @order and [Rental] = @rental" , con)

          Cmd.parameters.add(@CustomerName,sqlDbtype.Nvarchar).value = txtName.text
          Cmd.parameters.add(@address ,sqlDbtype.Nvarchar).value = txtaddress.text
          Cmd.parameters.add(@MobileNo ,sqlDbtype.Nvarchar).value = txtnumber.text
          Cmd.parameters.add(@order ,sqlDbtype.Nvarchar).value = txtorder.text
          Cmd.parameters.add(@rental ,sqlDbtype.Nvarchar).value = txtrental.text

          Dim i as integer = cmd.executenonquery() 

          If i > 0 then 
             txtAddress.Text = ""
              txtName.Text = ""
            txtOrder.Text = ""
            txtRental.Text = ""
            txtNumber.Text = ""
         
            MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted Successfuly", "Delete Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            CustomersBindingSource.MoveNext()
        else 
           messagebox.show("Something wrong..not deleted")
         end if 




         
      Else
            MessageBox.Show("Aborted!", "Prompt", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If


    End If
catch ex as exception 
   Messagebox.show("Error Occured..!!!" & vbcrlf & ex.message)
finally
   con.close() 
end try 
End Sub
```